# How to set name to a chip

Tags: html, angular, frontend, chips

I'm trying to give categories name to my chip in my Angular application. For the backend i use Spring Boot. I tried a lots to fix this error and i don't know if is a FrontEnd problem or a BackEnd problem.
The problem is that now my categories chips appears in this way:

[image]

But i want name instead of numbers.

Categories are defined in .\models\category

```
export enum Category {
  MANGA,
  DVD,
  LIBRI,
  COMICS
}
```

In .\components\categories\categories.component.html

```
<div class="categories">
  <div *ngFor="let category of categories"  class="category-item">
    <div (click)="handleClick(category)">
      <app-chip
        value={{category}}
        modifier="menu-item"
        ></app-chip>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my .ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-categories',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories.component.css']
})
export class CategoriesComponent implements OnInit {

  public categories: Category[] = [
    Category.MANGA,
    Category.DVD,
    Category.LIBRI,
    Category.COMICS
  ]


  constructor(private observableService: ObservableService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  handleClick(category: Category) {
    this.observableService.changeCategory(category);
  }
}
```

As result i want that my categories appears instead of the numbers in the chips.

Answer (score 0):

It's issue with your enum - by default enums are numbers, starting with 0. You can just assign them whatever strings you want:

```
export enum Category {
  MANGA = "MANGA",
  DVD = "DVD",
  LIBRI = "LIBRI",
  COMICS = "COMICS"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component's TypeScript file (.ts), define a method to map enum values to their corresponding names:

```
  getCategoryName(category: Category): string {
  switch (category) {
    case Category.MANGA:
      return 'Manga';
    case Category.DVD:
      return 'DVD';
    case Category.LIBRI:
      return 'Libri';
    case Category.COMICS:
      return 'Comics';
    default:
      return '';
  }
}
```

In your component's HTML file (e.g., category.component.html), use the Angular ngFor directive to iterate through the categories array and display their enum values:

```
  <div *ngFor="let category of categories">
  {{ getCategoryName(category) }}
</div>
```

However you can also maintain from backend as well.
Here is demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-enadky?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved it using your advice.

Comment: if this answer is helpful for you, please marks this answers.